Agrupar y borrar
Partimos de los siguientes datos
d1 <- read.table(text = '
col1    col2
z1  100
z5  101
z2  102
z2  103
z1  100
z4  101
z2  103
z1  107
z3  103
z5  107
z2  103
z2  189
z2  10
', header = TRUE)

Quiero agruparlos para ver que valores contiene z1, cuales z2 etc..
Resultado algo como esto:
 col1     col2    N
  z1      100     2
          107     1
---------------------
  z2      10      1
          102     1
          103     3
          189     1
----------------------
  z3      103     1
-----------------------
  z4      101     1
---------------------------
  z5      101     1
          107     1
-----------------------

Se me ocurre algo como esto, pero busco una forma directa de hacerlo.
d1%>%
  group_by(col1, col2) %>%
  summarise(
  N = n())-> d2

d2[c(2,4,5,6,10),1]<-""

d2
col1   col2     N
   <chr> <int> <int>
 1 "z1"    100     2
 2 ""      107     1
 3 "z2"     10     1
 4 ""      102     1
 5 ""      103     3
 6 ""      189     1
 7 "z3"    103     1
 8 "z4"    101     1
 9 "z5"    101     1
10 ""      107     1


Aquí una alternativa siguiendo tu lógica. La clave está en identificar los elementos repetidos (duplicated) en col1 para reemplazarlos por "" y así se logra el resultado deseado:
d1 %>%
  count(col1, col2) %>% # es equivalente a summarise(N = n(), .by = c(col1, col2))
  arrange(col1) %>% 
  mutate(col1 = ifelse(duplicated(col1), "", col1))

   col1 col2 N
1    z1  100 2
2        107 1
3    z2  102 1
4        103 3
5        189 1
6         10 1
7    z3  103 1
8    z4  101 1
9    z5  101 1
10       107 1

Si buscas una salida en formato html, entonces collapse_rows de kableExtra te puede servir:
library(kableExtra)
d1 %>% 
  count(col1, col2) %>% 
  arrange(col1) %>% 
  kable() %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F) %>%
  collapse_rows(columns = 1)

lo que genera:

